# Период у вещественных чисел

Tags: java, double

Поддерживается ли в java бесконечные периодические дроби? Например, что будет при делении 86 на 30?

Comment: Зачем такой сложный пример? Что будет при делении `1` на `3`?

Comment: У вас в компьютере бесконечный объем памяти? Если нет, то как вы думаете, можно ли в конечном объеме памяти хранить что-нибудь бесконечное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напрямую в языке - нет. 
Периодическая дробь это больше выражение чем число, а в Java нет такого типа данных.

Если есть необходимость таких точных вычислений то есть смысл создать класс описывающий Ваше выражение, которое будет вычисляться как можно ближе к месту использования.

P.S. `5 / 6 = 0.8333333333333334`

Comment: Если есть необходимость в точных вычислениях, то совершенно необязательно для этого создавать собственные классы. В подавляющем большинстве случаев вполне можно использовать стандартные классы `BigInteger` и/или `BigDecimal`. Для работы с рациональными числами можно использовать http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/Rational.html